# Neo4j Cypher query for finding connected nodes with a relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have to write a cypher query where I have employee node connected to each other. What i want that I have to find the employees who are not connected with me but have most common connections.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following perhaps :

```
MATCH (p1:Employee {name: "me"})-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(p2:Employee)<-[:CONNECTED_TO]-(p3:Employee)
WHERE NOT (p1)-[:CONNECTED_TO]-(p3)
AND p1 <> p3
RETURN p3.name AS Recommended, count(*) AS Strength ORDER BY Strength DESC
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom